# Preview locale does not work for Xcode 14.1

Tags: ios, xcode14, swiftui-previews

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/previewing-localizations), we should be able to set the `locale` on previews and the following code should work:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    
    var timeFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .full
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        return formatter
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(timeFormatter.string(from: Date.now))
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView().environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "fr_FR"))
    }
}
```

But it does not, and here is what I have in Xcode 14.1 (14B47b):

[image: preview screenshot]

Am I missing something? Is this a known issue?